# How to pass parameter with mobile.changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to open a new page by using `$.mobile.changePage` in jquery mobile,

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="main" data-role="page">

//using ajax call here, and got variable product_id
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image/' + employee.product_image +'" onClick="change_page('+employee.product_id+')">
</div>

<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page">
//if i click one of product from page main, will open this
//doing ajax call here
</div>
```

So the link will look like this `#detailsPage?id=xxxxx`

I want to bring the `product_id` variable to the next page (detailsPage)  by using function `change_page` like this

```
function change_page(pageid)
{
alert(pageid);

$.mobile.changePage("#detailsPage", { data : { 'id' : pageid },allowSamePageTransition:true}); //Samepagetransition to open same page based on ID


}
```

but it's not working.

Is there anything wrong with typing in my function?

and when i change parameter product_id, the page didnt changed.

Comment: Without knowing where you're getting those variable from, there's not much we can do to help. Is your image even loading?

Comment: i have updated my question